# Why is my textfield still editable even if i set enabled and editable to false?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jradiobutton

The two textfields `txt_d1` and `txt_d2` are set uneditable before i click any of the radio buttons.I want the textfield to be set uneditable again when i unselect the radio button `r_amount`. Why is it that even if I set enabled and editable to false, it is still editable? Here is my code.

```
int salary = Integer.parseInt(txt_salary.getText());
               
        if(r_percentage.isSelected() == true){
            
        int getPercentage = Integer.parseInt(txt_d1.getText());
        int calcPercentage = salary/100 * getPercentage + salary;
        String xP = String.valueOf(calcPercentage);
        txt_salary.setText(xP);
       
        
        
        }else if(r_amount.isSelected() == true){
               
        int getAmt = Integer.parseInt(txt_d2.getText());
        int calcAmount = salary + getAmt;
        String xA = String.valueOf(calcAmount);
        txt_salary.setText(xA);
        
        }

private void r_percentageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        //radio button percentage
        r_percentage.setSelected(true);
        r_amount.setSelected(false);
        txt_d2.setEnabled(false);
        txt_d1.setEnabled(true);
        txt_d1.setEditable(true);
        txt_d2.setText("");
     
    }   

private void r_amountActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

int clickCount = 0;
        ButtonGroup radioGroup = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton r_amount  = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

if (++clickCount % 2 == 0) {

            radioGroup.clearSelection();
            r_percentage.setSelected(false);
            r_amount.setSelected(false);         
            txt_d2.setEnabled(false);
            txt_d2.setEditable(false);
            txt_d2.setText("");
                   
        }else{
             
            r_amount.setSelected(true);
            r_percentage.setSelected(false);
            txt_d1.setEnabled(false);
            txt_d2.setEnabled(true);
            txt_d2.setEditable(true);
            txt_d1.setText("");
}
```

Comment: The code is note complete enough to be able to tell. At least add the radio button event code.

Comment: Some other part of the code might be undoing the settings here.  We'd really need a [mcve] for this.

Comment: Really sorry, im new here. I just updated the code, thank you

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Please read bot documents carefully, as what you've added above is an uncompileable code snippet, not an MRE / SSCCE (they're essentially the same thing, but the latter page gives a more complete description). 2) Tip: Add @markspace (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.